# AIC interpretation: why is lower AIC better?

Tags: interpretation, aic

Why is AIC interpreted as lower is better, intuitively, can someone explain?

I am running these two models, of which `m1` has lower AIC when compared to `m2` with fewer covariates, and so it would be the preferred model.

```r
 # m1 cornpix
> m1 <-lm(CornHec ~ CornPix, data = cornsoy)
> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = CornHec ~ CornPix, data = cornsoy)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-47.991 -13.662   2.316  13.657  35.305 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.81871   13.48779   0.506    0.616    
CornPix      0.38165    0.04417   8.641 3.34e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 18.64 on 35 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6809,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6718 
F-statistic: 74.67 on 1 and 35 DF,  p-value: 3.344e-10

> AIC(m1)
[1] 325.4222
> 
> 
> # cornpix
> m2 <-lm(CornHec ~ CornPix + SoyBeansPix, data = cornsoy)
> summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = CornHec ~ CornPix + SoyBeansPix, data = cornsoy)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-50.361 -13.431   0.721  13.349  35.194 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 18.29100   32.12735   0.569    0.573    
CornPix      0.36194    0.06705   5.398 5.22e-06 ***
SoyBeansPix -0.02759    0.06995  -0.394    0.696    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 18.87 on 34 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6823,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6636 
F-statistic: 36.51 on 2 and 34 DF,  p-value: 3.417e-09

> AIC(m2)
[1] 327.2533
```

Answer (score 3):

The AIC is defined as $-\ln \hat L(k)+2k$ where $L(k)$ is the estimated loglikelihood of the model in question, which has $k$ free parameters.

When finding a good model, we want the model to fit the data well (large $L(k)$) and we want the model to be not too complex (small $k$). This means that we want $\ln \hat L(k)$ to be large and $2k$ to be small, therefore a small AIC is better. (Of course in most cases a bigger $k$ will give a bigger $L(k)$, so that the AIC is about balancing the two.)

Annoyingly, in the literature there are both "larger is better" and "smaller is better" versions of the AIC around (different by a factor of -1). I have even seen both versions in different R-packages. This means that in order to interpret results always make sure you know whether your package gives you a "larger is better" or a "smaller is better" version (the former has plus the loglikelihood minus the $2k$ penalty; they are of course in principle equivalent, but it is confusing that both are in use and most authors don't tell you explicitly which one they use, same BIC).

Answer (score 1):

AIC has a component for the closeness of the fit (smaller is better) and a component for the number of parameters (again small is good, reflecting the principle of parsimony). So AIC tends to favour models which follow the data as closely as possible but with a minimum of parameters. Use of the AIC criterion can be shown to roughly mimic a likelihood ratio test between models, with a significance level of around 0.30. It therefore tends to overfit the data. A criterion that is closer to an alpha of 0.05 is the Schwarz Bayesian Criterion.

Comment: The *C* in *AIC* stands for *criterion*, so *AIC criterion* is a bit superfluous.

Comment: Are you sure about the significance level of ~0.30? E.g. if we are talking about nested models with just a single variable omitted from the bigger model, AIC cutoff corresponds to a $p$-value of about 0.16 (not 0.30) for the variable.

Comment: Richard, you may very well be correct. I seem to recall the 0.30 from a recent text I'd read on comparing AIC to LR tests (which of course I can't find at present). The essential learning is that the use of AIC typically results in an over-specified model although in some circumstances, eg prediction, this may be an advantage. It increases the chances of including important variables whilst depending on the theoretical unbiasedness of the parameter estimates to reflect the effect of the input variables.